# Why constructor is not called for given casting operator?

Tags: c++, constructor, compiler-errors, typecast-operator

```
struct A {}; 
struct B
{
  B (A* pA) {}
  B& operator = (A* pA) { return *this; }
};

template<typename T>
struct Wrap
{
  T *x; 
  operator T* () { return x; }
};

int main ()
{
  Wrap<A> a;
  B oB = a; // error: conversion from ‘Wrap<A>’ to non-scalar type ‘B’ requested
  oB = a;  // ok
}
```

When `oB` is constructed then Why `B::B(A*)` is NOT invoked for `Wrap<T>::operator T ()` ? [Note: `B::operator = (A*)` is invoked for `Wrap<T>::operator T ()` in the next statement]

Comment: Which compiler? Compiles fine on VS2010.

Comment: @Agnel Kurian, that's because VS2010 has a partial support for C++0x.

Comment: @Kirill: So, the above is valid in C++0x? Is that what you meant?

Comment: @Agnel Kurian, I've just looked at C++0x, no it is not valid. Seems to be it is extension or bug in VS2010.

Comment: with gcc 4.4.3 I can't get `B oB;` to compile, I have to do `B oB(a);`. So it's not clear to me what the `// ok` in the third line of `main` refers to.

Comment: @Andre, I have mentioned in the **Note** in my question, what the 3rd line means.

Comment: MSVC will give a warning, `warning C4928: illegal copy-initialization; more than one user-defined conversion has been implicitly applied`, but you have to pass `/Wall` to get it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that the number of user-defined conversions that are invoked implicitly is limited (to 1) by the Standard.

```
B ob = a;
```

implies two user conversions:

- on `a`: `Wrap<A>::operator A*()` should be called
- on the result: `B::B(A*)` should be called

*@James Kanze's explanation:* this syntax is called "copy initialization", effectively equivalent to `B ob = B(a)` (with the copy being elided most of the time). This is different from `B ob(a)` which is a "direct initialization" and would have worked.

if you explicitly qualify any of this, it will work, for example:

```
B ob = B(a);
```

On the other hand, for the second case there is no issue:

```
ob = a;
```

is short-hand for:

```
ob.operator=(a);
```

And thus only one user-defined conversion is required, which is allowed.

**EDIT**:

Since it's been required in a comment (to Kirill's answer) we can take a guess at the motive.

Chained conversions could be long, very long, and therefore:

- could surprise users -- implicit conversions may already be surprising as it is...
- could lead to an exponential search of the possibilities (for the compiler) -- it would need to go from both ends, trying to check all possible conversions, and somehow "join" the two (with the shortest path possible).

Furthermore, as long as there is more than 1 conversion, you run into the risk of having cycles, which would have to be detected (even though diagnostic would probably not be required, and be subject to Quality Of Implementation).

So, since a limit is necessary to avoid infinitely long searches (it could have been left unspecified, with a minimum required), and since beyond 1 we may have new issues (cycles), then 1 seems as good a limit as any after all.

Comment: +1 Correct answer. The Standard doesn't allow chained conversion. It allows one user-conversion in an expression.

Comment: This answer is only partially correct.  The key point here is the semantics of "copy initialization", as opposed to "direct initialization".

Answer (score 7):

It's because you're using "copy initialization".  If you write the
declaration of `oB`:

```
B oB(a);
```

, it should work.  The semantics of the two initializations are
different.  For `B oB(a)`, the compiler tries to find a constructor
which can be called with the given arguments.  In this case, `B::B(A*)`
can be called, because there is an implicite conversion from `Wrap<A>`
to `A*`.  For `B oB = a`, the semantics are to implicitly convert `a` to
type `B`, then use the copy constructor of `B` to initialize `oB`.  (The
actual copy can be optimized out, but the legality of the program is
determined as if it weren't.)  And there is no implicit conversion of
`Wrap<A>` to `B`, only of `Wrap<A>` to `A*`.

The assignment works, of course, because the assignment operator also
takes a `A*`, and so the implicit conversion comes into play.

Comment: +1 good point raised. I had a perception that `B oB = a;` and `B oB(a)` are same!

Comment: +1000. Nice. I didn't know the difference between the semantics of the two initializations.

Answer (score 5):

The Standard doesn't allow chained *implicit* conversion. If it was allowed, then you could have written such code:

```
struct A
{
   A(int i) //enable implicit conversion from int to A
};  
struct B
{
   B(const A & a); //enable implicit conversion from A to B
};
struct C
{
   C(const B & b); //enable implicit conversion from B to C
}; 
C c = 10; //error
```

You cannot expect that `10` will convert to `A` which then will convert to `B` which then converts to `C`.

---

```
B b = 10; //error for same reason!

A a = 10;        //okay, no chained implicit conversion!
B ba = A(10);    //okay, no chained  implicit conversion!
C cb = B(A(10)); //okay, no chained implicit conversion!
C ca = A(10);    //error, requires chained implicit conversion
```

---

The same rule applies for *implicit* conversion that invokes `operator T()` implicitly.

Consider this,

```
struct B {};

struct A 
{
   A(int i); //enable implicit conversion from int to A
   operator B(); //enable implicit conversion from B to A
};

struct C
{
   C(const B & b); //enable implicit conversion from B to C
}; 

C c = 10; //error
```

You cannot expect that `10` will convert to `A` which then will convert to `B`(using `operator B()`) which then converts to `C`.  S

Such chained *implicit* conversions are not allowed. You've to do this:

```
C cb = B(A(10);  //okay. no chained implicit conversion!
C ca = A(10);    //error, requires chained implicit conversion
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because C++ Standard allows only one user-defined conversion. According to §12.3/4:

> At most one user-defined conversion (constructor or conversion function) is implicitly applied to a single
>   value.

```
B oB = a; // not tried: ob( a.operator T*() ), 1 conversion func+1 constructor
oB = a;   // OK: oB.operator=( a.operator T*() ), 1 conversion func+1 operator=
```

As a workaround you can use explicit form of calling the constructor:

```
B oB( a ); // this requires only one implicit user-defined conversion
```

Comment: can you detail bit more. Especially what's the motive behind not allowing it.